# Share data between Azure web app and Onprem .net web application

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Angular2 MVC web application hosted on Azure App service and an Onprem web application. I have a scenario where i have a link in my Angular2 application which will call Onprem application and process something and return back to Azure app.
Question is how can i navigate from azure app to Onprem app and send certain data.I will have a back button in onprem app which will correctly redirect to Azure web app page where i have called Onprem application link.

Comment: Show your code what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

> Question is how can i navigate from azure app to Onprem app and send certain data.

To navigate from your azure app to another web application, you could use following JavaScript code. To send certain data, you could pass the data in query string.

```
window.location.href = "http://Onprem-url?data=data_to_pass";
```

On your Onprem web app site, you could get the data from query string. If your Onprem web app is written using ASP.NET.

```
string data = Request.QueryString["data"];
```